# Website only shows information of the first user to login through OpenID [NodeJS]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, steam

I am making a website that has users sign in with their steam credentials through OpenID, however when a second user logs in on a different account, the site displays the information (such as profile picture and username) of the first user to log into the site. I was having a lot of issues getting the json that the data was stored in to the client so I assume I made a mistake along the way.

This is the client side code that fetches the user data -

```
async function steamOpenId() {
const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(ownerSteamIdJson)
};
    const steamOpenIdResponse = await fetch('/userData', options);
    const testing = await steamOpenIdResponse.json();
    const profileImg = document.getElementsByClassName('profile-img')[0]
    const userName = document.getElementsByClassName('user-name')[0]
    profileImg.src = testing.photos[2].value
    userName.innerHTML = '<i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>' + testing.displayName
}
steamOpenId()
```

This is the server side code that sends and retrieves the user data -

```
// Required to get data from user for sessions
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user);
});
// Initiate Strategy
passport.use(new SteamStrategy({
    returnURL: 'http://localhost:' + port + '/api/auth/steam/return',
    realm: 'http://localhost:' + port + '/',
    apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    }, function (identifier, profile, done) {
        process.nextTick(function () {
            profile.identifier = identifier;
            return done(null, profile);
        });
    }
));
app.use(session({
    secret: 'LoopTrades',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
    maxAge: 3600000
    }
}))
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.user);
});
app.get('/api/auth/steam', passport.authenticate('steam', {failureRedirect: '/'}), function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/')
});
app.get('/api/auth/steam/return', passport.authenticate('steam', {failureRedirect: '/'}), function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/pages/deposit.html');
    app.post('/userData', (request, response) => {
        response.json(req.user)
    })
});
```

Any help making sure that each user has their own information displayed is much appriciated.

Many thanks :)

Comment: Debug your code and add debugging details. [_StackOverflow is a question-and-answer site for specific questions about actual code; “I wrote some buggy code that I can’t fix” is not a question, it’s a story, and not even an interesting story._](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Why would you use `app.post` inside `app.get`? That's probably a reason of the bug